# How can I store user preferences in WordPress and retreive them later?

Tags: plugins, php, database, users, cookies

I have a WordPress website where I want to give users some options to sepcify how they want to see the site. For example, they can choose from a given set of fonts, menu color etc.

I am assuming this will mean that I have to create a webpages where logged in users can check different boxes to set their preferences.

Is there a way to do that using something that takes advantage of the WordPress ecosystem instead of coding everything from scratch?

Basically, I want a dedicated webpage which logged in users can visit to set their preferences. :)

How can I do that in a way that allows me to take advantage of WordPress without coding everything myself?

To be clear, I have no problem in writing the code. What I meant to ask was if there are any WordPress functions or plugins that I can rely on to make it easier. :)

Comment: @DeCoder I can write code if needed but I would prefer not to do it from scratch. Every now and then, I have also gone through code of different plugins to make changes according to my needs. I just don't want to spend a lot of time writing code if someone has done something like this already. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two different approaches, Both require some coding.

1. **Using a Plugin**

   In your case, there are a lot of good plugins out there but If I'd like to give a name, you'll have to check [`Profile Extra Fields by BestWebSoft`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-extra-fields/) (I think it doesn't require a lot of coding) and [`Advanced Custom Fields`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) (It requires some coding but it worth, you can take a look at [this](https://usersinsights.com/acf-user-profile/) article to read more about how to add user fields in ACF)
2. **Coding from scratch using WordPress's built-in user functionalities**

   There are very good built-in functions like `get_user_meta`, `add_user_meta`, etc.

   They're very easy to use and they're very well integrated inside the WordPress platform. You can learn more about these functions and some more by looking into the [`users.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L0) file.

Comment: Thanks @Farsad. I did some research myself and found out about `update_user_meta()` and `add_user_meta()`. Should I use the functions you mentioned or the ones I found?

Comment: Use `add_user_meta` and `update_user_meta`, I'll edit my answer those I've mentioned are deprecated.

Comment: Or, even more semantic - `get_user_option()` etc.